# Create product with external attachment URL using REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am following documentation for create a product, https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product .

I want to create a product with the images which are saved in an external server.

when I use the following code the API uploading the src image to the current server,

```
'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
        ],
]
```

But I don't want to upload those images to the current server.

If I explain it in WordPress code without API,
1. I need to create parent post ( post type - post )
2. create another post with post type "attachment", content as external URL and parent post as above post's ID

But is there any chance to use the above woocommerce API for this requirement?